# Notifications about chat room messages

Tags: support, chat, notifications

To get someone notified about my message, should I use `@reply` syntax in *chat rooms*? Who will get notifications when I send a message to a chat room without `@reply`?

Comment: This question belongs on the mother meta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to notify someone you should @ them. If you don't @ anyone, nobody will be notified.

Comment: I hope you answered this considering **chat rooms**?

Comment: @ACB Yes. For posts the notification rules are [more complicated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125212/380389). Chat rooms are fairly simple- no @, no notification. (Additionally, you can't @ people that haven't been in the room for too long of a time).

Comment: @ACB Is there any reason you thought this answer wasn't considering chat rooms? Did something happen where you weren't notified in a chat room despite someone tagging you?

Comment: Note that chat pings don’t show up in your “global inbox” until 15 minutes after they’ve happened, and you can cancel that promotion-to-website by interacting with the chat room where the ping happens. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319354/280545).

Comment: @BioPhysicist , it happened. I realized that the other one didn't receive a notification about my message in the chat room, and also he has replied but I wasn't informed.